# How to estimate coefficients of a state space when relevant data is provided?

Tags: matlab, linear-dynamical-system

I have a state space system

$\dot{x}$ = $Ax$ + $Bu$

$y$ = $Cx$

I know C matrix exactly. And A matrix looks something like this, and some of the $x_{ij}$ in A are known as well. Same goes with B.

\begin{bmatrix}
    x_{11} & x_{12} & x_{13} & x_{14} \\
    x_{21} & x_{22} & x_{23} & x_{24} \\
    x_{31} & x_{32} & x_{33} & x_{34} \\
    x_{41} & x_{42} & x_{43} & x_{44}
\end{bmatrix}

Given input and output data, is it possible to identify the unknown coefficients and thus the system. One way could be to start with range of each of the coefficients and minimize the error. Are there any easy wasys? Is there a MATLAB toolbox or GUI which automates the process?

Comment: Is this not handled by the System Identification Toolbox in MATLAB? Seems like it should be, although I haven't used MATLAB in a long time.

Comment: I believe, the app is great for black box identification, and to my knowledge, there is no way to have this kind of system identified in the app. I may be wrong though

Comment: GKS, yes, you are wrong. Did you look at my answer and the links I provided?  That is exactly what you asked for, which is a very common situation in System Identification.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone I haven't tried it, but looks like this is it. Saw your profile, looks like you work on simulation optimization. Can you please visit this old question of mine? I have not got any solution for this?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29352215/optimization-in-nmpc-of-second-order-pendulum-model

Comment: I put a comment there. But really need more info.  As far as simulation optimization, I really mean optimization in which objective function and gradient are evaluated by stochastic (i.e., Monte Carlo) simulation, subject to deterministic (bound, linear, nonlinear, even semidefinite) constraints. But deterministic simulation, as apparently you have, is easier. On the other hand, I am not a SIMULINK guy, so don't know the various tricks associated with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very standard in System Identification. You have a "grey-box" model, i.e., partially known model and parameters.

MATLAB System Identification Toolbox, which I've never used, has several functions equipped for just this kind of situation.  See "Estimate State-Space Model for Partially Known Model (Structured Estimation)" in http://www.mathworks.com/help/ident/ref/ssest.html , http://www.mathworks.com/help/ident/ref/idss.html , and http://www.mathworks.com/help/ident/ref/greyest.html